# Cross platform software for Access application

Tags: cross-platform, microsoft-access

I have written a personal finance app in MS Acess and want to convert it to a cross platform app for Windows,Mac, Chrome, IOS and Android. What are my best options? In addition to Access, I have worked with Sql Server.

Comment: Access is a Windows-only program, therefore your database will only reliably work there. You ay give a try at LibreOffice or OpenOffice for Mac and Linux, with some chances of success depending on what have you used from Access. But for me, the easiest way would be to rewrite in something designed to be cross-platform.